# What is the difference between _tcslen and _tcsclen?

Tags: c++, function, winapi, string-length

I develop an application who has to be compatible with different charsets encoding. To do that, I always use `TCHAR*` instead of `char*` to define strings. Therefore I use `_tcslen` to get the size of my strings.

Today, I saw on the versioning system of my company that one of my workmate edited the line where I wrote `_tcslen` to use `_tcsclen` instead.

The only link I found who is talking about the particularity of this function is [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax.aspx) and it doesn't explain the difference between those functions.

Can someone explain me the difference between `_tcslen` and `_tcsclen`?

Comment: In the link you posted, yhey map onto different function depending on #define(s). If you need MBCS support then I think your workmate is correct.  See the remarks section.

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm sure he is correct. Indeed, we need MBCS because, I guess, the application is cross-platform and accept different charsets. But I don't really understand why we should prefer `_tcsclen` to `_tcslen`. What are the differences between them? In which cases should I use one or the other?

Comment: Pretty unlikely that you need to use TCHAR. You aren't supporting Windows 9x I guess.

Comment: Given that the length is probably being used for memory, rather than rendering (who does that manually?) purposes, the workmate is probably wrong and has introduced a serious bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `_t` prefix means that these are text handling functions (actually macros) that map to different implementations, depending on whether you're compiling for "Unicode" (actually UTF-16) or not.

When you're compiling for Unicode (`_UNICODE` is set), they map to the same function, `wcslen`, which returns the length of the string in wide (two-byte) characters.

When you're not compiling for Unicode (`_MBCS` is set), they map to different functions:

- `_tcslen` maps to `strlen`, which returns the length of the string in **bytes**. This is intended so that you can allocate buffers of the correct size.
- `_tcsclen` maps to `_mbslen`, the documentation for which is fairly sparse. I'm *guessing*, however that the `c` in `_tcsclen` is intended to mean **characters**.

The difference between characters and byte is that, in a multi-byte encoding, a particular character can take between one and three bytes. Thus: `_tcsclen` (`_mbslen`) tells you how many characters are in the string, which is useful for rendering, and `_tcslen` (`strlen`) tells you how many bytes are in the string, which you need for memory allocation.

In general, if you're working primarily on Windows, you'll just compile for Unicode and be done with it. You only need to deal with other character encodings if you're talking to another system (reading/writing files, network messages, etc.), and you'll usually convert to and from UTF-8.

Note that when the Windows SDK documentation refers to "multi-byte", it means older multi-byte encodings, such as Shift-JIS, rather than UTF-8 (which is *also* a multi-byte encoding).

Comment: *Unicode (actually UTF-16)* is not necessarily true I guess. You can also have unicode characters encoded as, say UTF-8?

Comment: @VijayChavda in Windows, "compiling for Unicode" means UTF-16. UTF-8 hadn't been invented at that point.

Comment: the c in _tcslen has to do with const. meaning it gives you the length of a const string pointer, be it a const char * or a const wchar_t *.

Answer (score 1):

> When the Windows **_MBCS** compiler flag is set, _tcslen maps to strlen and _tcsclen maps to _mbslen. When the Windows **_UNICODE** flag is set, the Generic functions both map to wcslen.